# How to add font-color and font-size in react/js ckeditor 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor 5 in my react project and i wanted to add font-Color in my editor. I am trying to add font plugin but i am getting error `ckeditor-duplicated-modules`. Any one work on this please tell me how to do this.

```
import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
import Font from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/font';

return (
    <div>
        <CKEditor
            editor={ClassicEditor}
            config={{
            plugins: [ Font ],
            toolbar: [
                'heading',  'bold', 'italic', 'fontColor','bulletedList', 'numberedList', 
                'undo', 'redo'
            ],
            fontColor: {
            colors: [
                {
                    color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 0%)',
                    label: 'Black'
                },
                {
                    color: 'hsl(0, 0%, 30%)',
                    label: 'Dim grey'
                },
                // ...
                ]
            },
            }}
            data={this.state.data}
            onChange={this.handleCkeditorState}
            onInit={(editor) => {
            this.setState({
                data: `<div>
                    ${messages.messageHTML}
                    </div>`,
            });
            }}
        />
    </div>
)
```

Error:
CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules

Comment: I'm trying to do this as well.  Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do this as well. Please help how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these:

1. Check your plugin version is the same as others plugins versions. e.g. at package.json - `"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^35.4.0",` so your ckeditor5-font package should match 35.4.0
2. Looks like you're just using `FontColor` plugin, so you don't need Font - is so, try replacing:

```
import { FontColor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font';


<CKEditor
  //...
  config={{
    plugins: [ FontColor ],
  }}
  //...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import both the plugin **Font** and the build **ClassicEditor** that way. You have to make a personal build.

Do not worry, that is quite easy though; just use their online builder : https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/. You will be able to pick the different font related plugins (and do not hesitate to optimize your building by removing all irrelevant plugins for your application), and build the default toolbar you want based on the plugins you will have selected.

Once done, in your component file:

- Remove imports of Font and ClassicEditor from your component
- import the custom editor from the build (e.g. `import MyEditor from '[customBuildLocation]/build/ckeditor'`)
- Use your custome editor as the editor of your CKEditor component
- Get rid of the plugins and toolbar configuration